# How to Execute A Complex SoX Command-Line String In Python

Tags: python, subprocess, sox

I'm trying to invoke SoX on the command line using the subprocess module in Python to process an audio file.

Python is complaining that it cannot find the files, however the same command works perfectly if invoked directly from the command line.

Therefore Python is not liking how I've constructed the command - I don't think it likes the double-quotes, but I can't figure out how to represent it with syntax Python accepts. Here is the command Python doesn't like:

```
s = ['sox', '-m', 'path/to/silence.wav',
     '"|sox path/to/audio1.wav -p pad 0"',
     '"|sox path/to/audio2.wav -p pad 5"',
     '"|sox path/to/audio3.wav -p pad 10"',
     'path/to/output.wav']
subprocess.call(s)
```

Here is the same command invoked from the command line that works:

```
sox -m path/to/silence.wav "|sox path/to/audio1.wav -p pad 0" "|sox path/to/audio2.wav -p pad 5" "|sox path/to/audio3.wav -p pad 10" path/to/output.wav
```

If any Python gurus could give an example of how to execute this in a .py, that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please, post your solution as an answer and then accept it by yourself. This way everyone with this issue (and also everyone who are willing to help you) will clearly know that the question has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Then delete your EDIT from question body. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, I only had to remove the double quotes... Silly me. Here's the correct Python code to the above example:

```
s = ['sox', '-m', 'path/to/silence.wav',
     '|sox path/to/audio1.wav -p pad 0',
     '|sox path/to/audio2.wav -p pad 5',
     '|sox path/to/audio3.wav -p pad 10',
     'path/to/output.wav']
subprocess.call(s)
```